# my question is in regard to continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Suppose $f:[3;7]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $f(x)\ge 6$ for all $x\in [3,7)$, prove that $f(7)\ge 6$.

I would just like someone to check my proof.

Suppose to the contrary $f(7)<6$, since $f$ is continuous, we have that there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t. $|x-7|<\delta\implies |f(x) - f(7)|< 6-f(7)$ but then we have $f(x) -f(7) < 6-f(7)$ and so $f(x) < 6$, but since this is only true for $f(7)$, it must be that $\delta=0$ a contradiction.

Is this correct? How could I do it with the sequential definition of continuity. This is not for a class, I am studying because students are asking me these questions in the tutoring lounge I work in and I forgot how to do them...

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: Your conclusion that $\delta  = 0$ does not follow from your argumentation, since you conclude that $f(x) < 6$ for $x \neq 7$. This means that your assumption $f(7) < 6$ was false.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain what you are saying here a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Using continuity of $f$ we see
$$f(7) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(7-1/n) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} 6 = 6$$

Comment: The limit here is not $\lim 6$ since $7-1/n \to 7.$

Comment: $f(7-1/n) \geq 6$ ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Andre-- Yes I read too quickly, didn't notice it was $\ge$ between the two. (+1 on answer)

Comment: Where does the inequality come from?

Comment: Hey, you can prove the following: If $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ and $a_n \geq b_n$ for large $n$, then $a \geq b$. This is equivalent to the fact, that the non-negative numbers are closed.

Comment: ahh and this falls from the fact that a_n-b_n>0 implies lim an - lim bn >= 0

Comment: Yes $a_n-b_n \geq 0$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n-b_n) \geq 0$ but the latter is $a-b$.